# HTML 5 App local database

Tags: database, html, windows-phone-8

I am creating a Q & A app for Windows 8 Phone.

These Q & A are about 100 or so and will never change.

I am not familiar with Windows 8 Phone SDK so I have decided to stick with the HTML 5 template for this.

Now I need to save/store these QA somewhere I do not want to involve the use of database, as this is a pretty simple app that I am making and I dont want it to connect to / depend on server, I want users to be able to use and read all QA even when they are offline.

So, with these requirement I could only think of storing these QA in json format and then using jquery to read and populate the QA into HTML.

```
{
    "categoryName": "Animal",
    "categoryId": 1,
    "QA": [
        {
            "question": "Which animal barks ?",
            "answer": "dog"
        },
        {
            "question": "Which animal moos ?",
            "answer": "cow"
        },
    ]
}

{
    "categoryName": "Grammar",
    "categoryId": 2,
    "QA": [
        {
            "question": "Opposite of men ?",
            "answer": "women"
        },
        {
            "question": "Vowels ?",
            "answer": "AEIOU"
        },
    ]
}
```

Are there any other approaches which you can suggest ?

Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: are you going to use [HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 2):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) you should be able to use HTML5 IndexedDB with IE10

Answer (score 1):

You say the data will never change, so I don't see why you need to use HTML5 IndexedDB.

You don't even need to store it in JSON format, just create the JS objects directly for optimal performance:

```
var data = [{
    categoryName: "Animal",
    categoryId: 1,
    QA: [
        {
            question: "Which animal barks ?",
            answer: "dog"
        },
        {
            question: "Which animal moos ?",
            answer: "cow"
        },
    ]
},
{
    categoryName: "Grammar",
    categoryId: 2,
    QA: [
        {
            question: "Opposite of men ?",
            answer: "women"
        },
        {
            question: "Vowels ?",
            answer: "AEIOU"
        },
    ]
}];
```